# How to add field in gravity form without error?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add field in gravity form but it gives me error as :-

```
admin.php?page=gf_edit_forms&id=4:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    at sack.runResponse (tw-sack.min.js?ver=1.6.1:1)    
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (tw-sack.min.js?ver=1.6.1:1)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that's causing that issue?

Comment: can you post your js code or the request you are hitting admin.php?page=gf_edit_forms&id=4:1

Comment: Had same error, was a problem in my functions.php ( get_sidebar() was being called )